# How to trace a "unexpected '?'" syntax error in a Laravel/PHP app?

Tags: laravel

I deployed my Laravel application to my web hosting site. Everything transferred successfully, but every time I login I get some message about parse syntax unexpected ? but its not telling me where its coming from this happens also on my other pages.

I'm using PHP 7.0 on my hosting site and Laravel 5.4. it will mean so much if you can help me understand what is going on. I can't provide you with a code because I don't know where the error is coming from. It doesn't tell me what line or anything. Please do not tell me the solution is in this similar question where it says "parse error" duplicate because I tried that and nothing happened

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: is your host laravel and php version the same with your local computer?

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted the error.

Comment: @Julianv.dBerkmortel I posted it

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin I'm not using my local computer im using web hosting and im using 7.0 and laravel version 5.4

Comment: Is there any code you could show where the syntax is supposed to be?

Comment: @Julianv.dBerkmortel I don't know what to show you cause its not telling me where. Awe man please tell me there's a solution for this cause I've been up all night haven't gotten any sleep because of this.

Answer (score 0):

The question marks are a feature of php 7.1. As you have said in the comments, the version on the server is only 7.0.

see http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php for more information about this feature.

Comment: but my hosting site dose'nt have php 7.0 what i'm a supposed to do

Comment: There are two main options: You either use a different hosting website or you analyse your code for nullable types and change it accordingly

Comment: I'll go ahead and analyze my code for nullable types instead. How should I go about this?

Comment: You do a global search in your project for question marks. You will then have to carefully examinate whether or not the types can be null or not. If they can be null you remove the type hint, If they can't be null you remove the question mark.

I'm afraid it'll have to be done on a case by case basis.

Comment: I'm sorry for all the questions but like is there a specific file in laravel I have to do this? like on vendor/symfony/translation/MessageCatalogue.php or what?

Comment: what if I change my php version to 5.6 will that help?

Comment: Don't worry about all the questions. Downgrading you php version would make it even worse as you will not be able to do any typehinting. You should never change files in your vendor folder as they are managed by composer, everytime you will run a composer update command those changes will be undone. If there are files in you vendor folder that do use Nullable type hinting you should downgrade to an earlier version via the composer.json file.

Comment: what version should i go with then. and are talking about php or laravel?

Comment: You should prefer version 7.1. Can you see at what file the parse error gets thrown?

Comment: But you remember my hosting site dosen't have php 7.1, but you said do it via the composer.json how will do that? I never tried downloading php through composer.json

Comment: You installed laravel with a composer command. Composer will install all packages ans source files from other 'vendors', hence the name of the folder. But in order to help identify the package that uses php 7.1 features i should really know the name of the file the parsing error triggers.